# Не работает тип string в классе

Tags: c++, строки

Что нужно добавить или поменять?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class point {
private:
    double x1, y1;
    
public:
    friend class circle;
};
class circle {
private:
    point x;
    double r;
    string color;
public:
    circle() {
        x.x1 = 0;
        x.y1 = 0;
        r = 0;
        color = "black";
    }
    circle(double x1, double y1, double r) {
        this->x.x1 = x1;
        this->x.y1 = y1;
        this->r = r;
    }
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что значит - "не работает"?

Comment: В общем-то в ошибках все сказано, ключевая информация - во второй. "Не найден спецификатор типа" значит, что компилятор  не опознал тип ```string``` Либо Вы не подключили файл с определением этого типа, либо что-то неправильно указали пори объявлении переменной. Могу предположить, что тип должен указываться как ```std::string``` но , возможно, я ошибаюсь

Comment: Спасибо, using namespace std; помог)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить к

```
#include <iostream>
```

две строки:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Можно без последней, но тогда использовать не `string`, а `std::string`.